# How can I add two splash screen's in my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am making an app in which I have put a default.png in the areas provided and added `sleep(5);` to my app delegate and currently it runs fine.

What I need to do is add more than one image when the app starts, so that I get one splash screen for 2.5 seconds and another one for 2.5 seconds.

How can I show 2 splash screens at start up?

Comment: Don't the app stall on startup, this is against the [HIG](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5). "Because users are likely to switch among applications frequently, you should make every effort to cut launch time to a minimum, and you should design a launch image that downplays the experience rather than drawing attention to it."

Answer (score 4):

Two splash screens are not possible. Create a viewcontroller with UIImageView filled with second image and show it for 2.5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add your image to your view controller and after 2.5 second, remove it from your view.

Comment: This answer is just a copy of Apurv who answered it earlier. It doesn't add anything extra

Comment: Apurv is saying to create a viewcontroller with UIImageView....and i am saying to add only imageView...8-)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily implement your view on top of the main view but in your appDelegate. For example, if you want a splash image that fades out to the main view: (or a default image that seems to fade out: just put the same image on the splash screen and the default screen). This gives you also the right orientation as long as it is the main view's.

Just add it in your

**application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:**

method:

```
UIImageView*imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your_default_image_or_First.png"]];
[[firstViewController view] addSubview:imageView];
[[firstViewController view] bringSubviewToFront:imageView];
[NSThread SleepForTimeInterval:(2.5)];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your_default_image_or_Second.png"]]
// as usual
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

//now fade out splash image
[UIView transitionWithView:self.window duration:1.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^(void){imageView.alpha=0.0f;} completion:^(BOOL finished){[imageView removeFromSuperview];}];
```

Answer (score -3):

Hi please try with following code its really hwlp full for you dear i suggested to use this one.....

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions

{

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

// Override point for customization after application launch.

MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController] autorelease];

UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.bounds] autorelease];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Welcome.png"];
if (!image)
{
    NSLog(@"Something went wrong trying to get the UIImage. Check filenames");
}

imageView.image = image;

[self.window addSubview:imageView];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

[self performSelector:@selector(removeFirstSplash:) withObject:imageView afterDelay:3];

return YES;
```

}

-(void)removeFirstSplash:(UIImageView *)oldImageView

{

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.bounds] autorelease];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Splash.png"];

imageView.image = image;

[self.window addSubview:imageView];

[self performSelector:@selector(removeSecondSplash:) withObject:imageView afterDelay:3];

[oldImageView removeFromSuperview];
```

}

-(void)removeSecondSplash:(UIImageView *)oldImageView

{

```
[self.window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];

[oldImageView removeFromSuperview];
```

}

Comment: this place is full of rascals ;)

Comment: This place is really full of rascals and we are among them.. big cheers for that ;)